# Datagrid MenuItem Image not displaying

Tags: c#, wpf, datagrid

I can't get my image to show up on my DataGrid ContextMenu MenuItem.Icon.  I know the icon exists under Resources but every time I run the code no image is displayed on anything.

```
       <DataGrid.ContextMenu>
            <ContextMenu x:Name="ContextMenu">
                <MenuItem Header="Edit" Click="EditItem_Click" >
                    <MenuItem.Icon>
                        <Image Source="Resources\Copy.png" Stretch="Fill"/>
                    </MenuItem.Icon>
                </MenuItem>
            </ContextMenu>
        </DataGrid.ContextMenu>
```

Comment: Did you try using full [path](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa970069(v=vs.110).aspx): `pack://application:,,,/MyAssemblyName;component/Resources/Copy.png`?

Comment: Tried this and it didn't fix the issue. Build action of the file made all the difference.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Make sure the Icon file is included in your project and also change the **Build Action** of that icon file as Resources. For **Build Action**, go to the properties of that file.

Make sure the following application path:

```
pack://application:,,,/AssemblyName;component/Resources/Copy.png
```

Also have a look on [here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa970069%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) to know about the UPI examples..

Comment: Just tried it, and changing the the build action of the icon file to resources fixed the issue, thanks!